# How to call service layer method from thymeleaf on button click

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot application that sends email notifications with certain details and has the option to Accept and Decline it. For the I am using the below thymeleaf template and setting the required context variables as well but getting the below message

**TemplateProcessingException: Only variable expressions returning numbers or booleans are allowed in this context, any other datatypes are not trusted in the context of this expression, including Strings or any other object that could be rendered as a text literal. A typical case is HTML attributes for event handlers (e.g. "onload"), in which textual data from variables should better be output to "data-*" attributes and then read from the event handler. (template: "notificationEmail" - line 47, col 17)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:lang="${#locale.language}" lang="en">
<head>
    <title th:text="#{email.notification.title}">Notification Alert</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
<p>
    Hi Team,<br>
    Below are the changes found in the table
</p>
<table border="1" style="width:750px">
    <tr>
        <td><b>File</b></td>
        <td><b>Entity</b></td>
        <td><b>Client</b></td>
        <td><b>Timestamp</b></td>
        <td><b>Changes</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${notification.fileName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${notification.entity}"></td>
        <td th:text="${notification.client}"></td>
        <td th:text="${notification.timestamp}"></td>
        <td th:text="${notification.changes}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
    Would you like to approve the changes -
</p>
    <button th:onclick="${@emailApproveService.method()}">Yes</button> 
    <button th:onclick="${@emailDeclineService.method()}">No</button>
<p>
    <span>Regards, </span>
    <br/>
    <em>Team ABC.</em>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
@Override
    public void sendNotificationEmail(NotificationDTO notificationDTO) throws MessagingException {
        NotificationDTO notificationDTOWithDetail= fileUtil.getFieldsFromFileName(notificationDTO);
        
        String lang = defaultThymeleafLang;
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(lang);
        Context context = new Context(locale);
        context.setVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME,
            new ThymeleafEvaluationContext(applicationContext, null));
        context.setVariable(NOTIFICATION, notificationDTOWithDetail);
        context.setVariable("emailApproveService",emailApproveService);
        context.setVariable("emailDeclineService",emailDeclineService);
        String content = templateEngine.process("notificationEmail", context);
        String subject =
                messageSource.getMessage(
                        "email.notification.subject",
                        new Object[] {
                                notificationUtil.getNotificationSubject(
                                        notificationDTOWithDetail.getApplicationName())
                        },
                        locale);
        String primaryNotifiers = notificationUtil.getPrimaryNotifiers(notificationDTOWithDetail.getApplicationName());
        String ccNotifiers =  notificationUtil.getCcNotifiers(notificationDTOWithDetail.getApplicationName());

        sendEmail(primaryNotifiers, ccNotifiers, subject, content, false, true);
    }
```

---

**EDIT**

As suggested I have created a new endpoint and trying to call it from the thymeleaf using the `<button th:onclick="@{http://localhost:8082/decline}">No</button>` and I get the email to accept or decline the details but in mail No button does not look like button and seems just like normal text and nothing happens when I click on it

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class EmailDeclineResource {

    private final EmailDeclineService emailDeclineService;
    EmailDeclineResource(
            EmailDeclineService emailDeclineService){
        this.emailDeclineService=emailDeclineService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/decline")
    public String decline() {
        ...
        return "decline result";
    }
}
```

Comment: Make an endpoint that calls the service method and have the thymeleaf code call that.

Comment: Thanks @NathanHughes Create an endpoint and call that endpoint on button click is it the way you are suggesting? Can you please share some example how I can call endpoint on button click

Comment: i have fixed it by using the `<button th:onclick="@{http://localhost:8082/decline}">No</button>` but API is not beign called and when I get email to accept or decline the details I am not able to click the button it is just look like text and not button

Answer (score 1):

To use the `sendNotificationEmail` method, you must first create an endpoint in your controller class that corresponds to the button in your Thymeleaf template. When the user clicks the button, an HTTP POST request is sent to the endpoint, triggering the sendNotificationEmail method.

Example:

```
@Controller
public class YourController{


@Autowired
private NotificationService notificationService;

@PostMapping("/send-notification-email")
public String sendNotificationEmail(@ModelAttribute("notificationDTO") NotificationDTO notificationDTO) throws MessagingException {
    notificationService.sendNotificationEmail(notificationDTO);
    return "email-sent";
}
```

}

In the above controller `NotificationService` class will be holding your logic and will be annotated with `@Component` so that you can `@Autowire` it in your `Controller`

And then finally you can map this end-point using `th:action="@{/send-notification-email}"`

**Change**

`<button th:attr="onclick='location.href=\'' + @{/send-notification-email} + '\''" type="submit">Yes</button>`

And it'll work

Comment: I hope this resolves your problem if not let me know in comments

Comment: Hello Daksharaj, Thanks for the answer I have tried to follow the way you have suggested but getting the error which I have updated in the question. Can you please check it?

Comment: It should fix your issue, if yes please mark it as answered

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I have tried to use `<button th:attr="onclick='location.href=\'' + @{http://localhost:8082/decline} + '\''" type="submit">No</button>` but it seems like normal No text and does not feel like button and nothing happens when I click on it. i will surely accept the answer once I am successfully able to hit the endpoint

Comment: Do you have a `/decline` endpoint? If yes, then No worries, you need to remove the localhost part and compare it with what I've written, you need to remove it because the Thymeleaf template and java code is running on the same server it will look something like this: `<button th:attr="onclick='location.href=\'' + @{/decline} + '\''" type="submit">No</button>`

Comment: It will only work if you have a `/decline` endpoint in your controller

Comment: Yes I have `/decline` endpoint as mentioned in the question. I have tried to use `<button th:attr="onclick='location.href=\'' + @{/decline} + '\''" type="submit">No</button>` but I am getting the emplateProcessingException: Link base \"/decline\" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template: \"notificationEmail\" - line 67, col 9)"

Comment: If I use the form I am able to hit the endpoint but it redirect to other page which is not required as per the client requirement

Comment: In your controller return the String

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252024/discussion-between-anonymous-and-daksharaj-kamal).